Regularization scheme preserving conformal symmetry?
I am doing some perturbative calculation on some conformal field theory like ${\cal N}=4$ SYM in $D=4$. For the not-protected correlators, some divergence might occur. However, usual regularization schemes like dimensional regularization and Pauli-Villars regularization might break the conformal symmetry of the theory (${\cal N}=4$ SYM is conformal at $D=4$ and other regularization will directly introduce an energy scale).
So if there is any other better regularization schemes that preserves the conformal symmetry?
